Ubuntu 22.04 on Thinkpad X13, Thunderbolt keyboard not working during drive decryption process
I've just ported from Thinkpad X390 Yoga to Thinkpad X13 2-in-1 Yoga.
The configuration is 1:1 (Ubuntu 22.04). I use an encrypted LVM drive. The problem I face with my next X13 is that I cannot use an external keyboard connected to the Thunderbolt dock (HP) when providing a passphrase to decrypt the drive (this is an early stage of the boot process, but I believe the OS is already loaded, as the boot partition seems to be unencrypted). It worked like a charm on the X390 but not the new X13. I use the same dock and hardware configuration for both devices.
To be clear, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on the X13 from scratch, keeping defaults during installation, and it is precisely the same OS configuration as the one I used on the X390.
When I pass the stage of decrypting the drive, I can easily use a connected keyboard to log in to the Gnome desktop—everything works fine.
The Kernel is 6.8.0-45-generic.
Interestingly, only the USB keyboard does not work during the decryption passphrase-providing stage of boot. All two external displays are on and present the screen with the passphrase input box, so I consider the Thunderbolt to be working correctly and authorised at this stage.
Any hints on how to troubleshoot the case are more than welcome; thanks in advance.
Peter

Does the Thinkpad X13 have Fast Boot or Fast Startup enabled in the BIOS? The reason for asking is that How to enable USB keyboard support when booting from an encrypted disk for Manjaro Linux said the Fast Boot BIOS  option prevented a USB keyboard from being able to be used to enter the encryption password. This is a comment, and not an answer, since not sure if it also applies to Ubuntu and a Thinkpad X13 .

@ChesterGillon, thanks for the quick hint. I've changed from Quick to Diagnostic and added a 10s delay (a feature to detect monitors during BIOS time), but it didn't help. The USB keyboard works because it operates OK in the BIOS, and the GRUB menu is displayed before the drive unlock screen appears. So, the problem is specific to this moment of unlocking the drive. KB works before and works after, but not then.

There seems to be a bug in Kernel 6.8.0-45, which was shipped with the Ubuntu 22.04.5 installation.
I've updated the Kernel to 6.5.8 (using mainline), and now, voila, it just works.
